# 2010 Lincoln MKS - Wobbling/shaking side to side

Tags: suspension, shaking, death-wobble

So I just recently bought a 2010 Lincoln MKS with 200,000 miles on it. Brakes, and new tires were allegedly put on it very recently. The car was brought back in for previously agreed upon (and paid for) shocks as the car would wobble as if I hit a pothole or something when I drove on a completely smooth road. As well as the shocks being put in, bushings were also installed. All this added up to the car being in the garage for a lengthy spell. And I was all too eager to get my car back when it was “done”. When I took the car and headed back to work I felt the same problem but I thought maybe the car needed a little time to adjust. As I went to go run errands and play sports, I realized that nothing had changed. I plan to bring the car back in because I am nothing short of furious right now. I would just like to know what possible problems could be causing this unnecessary shaking. The steering wheel doesn’t shake and the tires don’t shift and there is no noises, but the body of the car shifts around and it’s annoying and uncomfortable. Any insights or recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Matt here,20+ years experience in auto service.

is yours a Front-wheel drive or an all-wheel drive? Does the car drive in a straight line? Does it shake wobble all the time or only under certain condition ie. when hitting the brakes, at a certain speed, only when turning left? More information would help. pictures of the front end from under the car would help even more.

the MKS is a pretty big car, weighing over 3700 lbs (4200 for an AWD model), which is asking the front tire/suspension to do a lot of work. And with 200k miles on the clock its been working very hard for a very long time. shake/wobble issues can be hard to diagnose, as there are dozens of possible causes. assuming the parts you mentioned were actually replaced, then the first thing I'd check are your front hub/bearings, ball joints,  and tie-rod ends. If you can get the front tires off the ground (one at a time) grab the tire at 3 o'clock and 9 o'clock and see if there is any movement side to side if there is play then your tie-rod ends are probably the cause of your issues. movement at the 6/12 o'clock position suggests bearing/ball joint issues. its also possible that the front CV (constant velocity, BTW)) axles need replaced. if the black rubber boots that cover the CV joints are torn then they will sling all the grease out and eventually cause driveability issues.

whatever the cause, if any of the suspension parts are worn to the point they produce a noticeable shake while driving then the car probably isn't safe to drive. trust me, you do not want to be in, or anywhere near the car when a tie-rod end separates at 70MP. And for what it's worth, i would advise against taking it back to the same shop, because any of the things i've mentioned would have been pretty obvious.